# How do I "link" two or more rows of the same table with a unique "link" id?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am looking for a better way to create a link between **two or more** rows of the same table, but the link itself must have a unique ID. What I am currently doing seems rather convoluted. I have a `positions` table that I am "linking" via the table `linked_positions`, but using yet a tertiary link via the `linked_positions_1nf` table. Perhaps it will be easier to see the structures with some sample data...

```
mysql> SELECT id FROM positions WHERE id IN (104, 105);
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 104 |
| 105 |
+-----+

mysql> SELECT id, linked_ids position_ids FROM linked_positions LIMIT 1;
+----+--------------+
| id | position_ids |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | 104, 105     |
+----+--------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM linked_positions_1nf WHERE link_id = 1;
+-----+---------+-------------+
| id  | link_id | position_id |
+-----+---------+-------------+
| 123 |       1 |         104 |
| 124 |       1 |         105 |
+-----+---------+-------------+
```

It seems like it would be more ideal to only have one linking table to achieve the above, but I haven't been able to find a more refined solution. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Not clear what you are up to. The `linked_positions.position_ids` seems not be needed as a column (can be calculated) and the `linked_positions_1nf.id` is not needed as well, the `(link_id, position_id)` could be used as the PK.

Answer (score 1):

If the ID in your 'link' table absolutely has to be unique, and if it's ALWAYS a link between two IDs, you could use 3 columns: ID, min_position, max_position. That would allow you to use joins with your positions table.

I'm a bit confused regarding the goal of your application, i must admit ;).